# What does 覆ってみせる mean?

Tags: words, subsidiary-verbs

As far as I can tell from the components, it means to show yourself hiding which makes no sense. Context is the sentence ＸはＹに顔を覆ってみせる

Answer (score 2):

顔を覆って  == cover one's face (with both hands)

-みせる == that it was done largely to show other person(s)

X did it to show Y -- Sometimes it's fake (pretending to be sad, shocked, etc.). Other times, the "pretending" sense is weak or almost non-existent.

てみせる has other uses :

> http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=miseru 
> 今年こそは修士論文を書き上げてみせる。
>
> 今年、僕は大学を卒業してみせる｡  
> You will see, This year I will graduate.

㋑強い決意を表す。「絶対に勝って―・せる」

So a better translation may be:

- This year I will graduate college, for sure.
- This year I will graduate from college, and that's a promise.

Comment: The ～てみせる in the OP's sentence 覆ってみせる is definition #10-㋐「実際にその行為をして、人に示す」in [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/211967/meaning/m0u/), while the ～てみせる in your examples 書き上げてみせる/卒業してみせる is definition #10-㋑「強い決意を表す。」.